# nmap how to scan only RDP open ports from range 1024-50000?

Tags: nmap

nmap,how to scan ''only'' RDP's ALL open ports?For example i scan 1 range for rdp open port 3333 using this syntax: `nmap -p3333 -Pn IpCidrRange/17 --open -oG save.txt` and i got 100 results of which worked for RDP just 5.Who can tell me which is the right syntax to get only the Ip's with open port exclusively for rdp?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should scan a range of ports from 1020-50000

> nmap -p1024-50000 -Pn IpCidrRange/17  -oA save